# Cinemas in Prague with love seats or armrests that go up?

Tags: prague, cinema

Visiting Prague again with my girlfriend this time and we will likely go to the movies. She hates it when there are armrests, so I was wondering, are there any cinemas in Prague that offer love seats or at the very least armrests that go up?

Googling and looking at some interior shots didn't work out, so asking here instead.

Comment: I'm no connoisseur of cinemas, but I've never seen a cinema anywhere where the chairs lacked armrests.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Like you mean loveseats in the cinema? Something like this on the back row is quite easy to find in some countries: http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/11/09/1415535780364_wps_58_BNPS_co_uk_01202_558833_P.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only cinema which has "love seats" in every screening is [Premiere Cinemas](http://www.premierecinemas.cz/). The wide seating sections are the seats you're looking for:

[image]

Other cinemas (e.g. [Cinestar Andel](http://cinestar.cz/cz/praha5/domu)) have the right seats in some of their screens, but you can't guarantee it.